# Format ValueAmimator setText with decimal format Android JAVA

Tags: java, android, decimalformat, animator

I have a animated setText display. I take the string value from the JSON response and display it with valueAnimator.

I need to format the final setText in 1000s format (#,###)

e.g.

currently I get: 50125

Expected: 50,125

```
                   DecimalFormat decim = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
                    //Total no animate
                    ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
                    animator.setObjectValues(0, Integer.parseInt(total_no));
                    animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                        public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
                            tvtotal_no.setText(String.valueOf(animation.getAnimatedValue()));
                          //tvtotal_no.setText(decim.format(Integer.parseInt(total_cases)));
                        }
                    });
                    animator.setDuration(500);
                    animator.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to actually use the DecimalFormat:

```
DecimalFormat decim = new DecimalFormat("#,###");
//Total no animate
ValueAnimator animator = new ValueAnimator();
animator.setObjectValues(0, Integer.parseInt(total_no));
animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animation) {
          tvtotal_no.setText(decim.format(animation.getAnimatedValue()));
    }
});
animator.setDuration(500);
animator.start();
```